# How to wrap quotes around variable value in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a variable

```
test=value.txt
```

I am using test as

```
$test
```

which gives me

```
value.txt
```

I want result as

```
'value.txt'
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**
Above is just an example of the task I am trying to achieve. I can't change variable value.

Comment: This sure sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to pass this value to a command without it breaking on spaces or because you think the command requires single quotes, you are not on the right track.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assignment using string:

```
test="'value.txt'"
echo "$test"
'value.txt'
```

Assignment using variable:

```
var=value.txt
test="'$var'"
echo "$test"
'value.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
test="'value.txt'"
```

or this:

```
test=\'value.txt\'
```

Comment: I can't control value insertion to the variable. It is an example of the data I am using.

Comment: Sure you can. `test=\'$test\'`

Answer (score 1):

```
test=aaa
test="'$test'"
echo $test
```

output:

```
'aaa'
```